# How to allow extensionless url for subdomains on localhost?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, localhost

I have set up up subdomain m.localhost with vhost. m.locahost is point to htdocs/m/ folder

I want both `m.localhost/page` and `m.localhost/page.php` to be working and show as `m.localhost/page`. On my production site,I have something like this on my .htaccess file and it is working fine:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=302,L,NE]    

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!m/).*)$ m/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

I use a similar technique on localhost but it's not working. I got directed to the localhost (not m.). But if I delete the .htaccess files, .php files are working fine.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.localhost$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!m/).*)$ m/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

How can I make it to behave similarly as my production site? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally added `AllowOverride All` to the vhost settings, things went fine afterwards.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName m.localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/m/"   
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/m">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```